# Using NLTK to design a search engine

Tags: python, search, nltk

I'm creating a database for documents and related files.  I am running OCR on documents which require that, and pulling the text from documents which have that available.  So from there I am trying to gather as much information and store them in a database.

I've ran across this library called NLTK, and read some about database design.  It appears that collocations are what are suggested.  Currently I am collection bigram and trigram collocations, but I have noticed that it is selecting things which are far too specific to the document text and not broad enough (such as titles).

My questions/thoughts are as follows:

- It does not seem better for searching to have specific collocations such as [hip,replacement,surgery] when it could be a document about insurance costs in general.  So for example, we could have multiple documents that have that same trigram and be set for a different time period.
- Due to the above, is there a way to filter out common and expected collocations in multiple sets of OCR results?
- Are there other sets of data which are more or significantly valuable to the search function?

I am here to better understand what I am trying to accomplish, and I honestly do not know much.  So any help is much appreciated, and if you could imagine me being incredibly naive so I may need a very basic explanation.

Comment: I think whoosh might be easier to get started with... (https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/wiki/Home)

Comment: @thebjorn this looks promising, but my understanding is that whoosh is a flat file database or where is this data stored?

Comment: Whoosh (and any other full-text search) extracts data into an index that is created for efficient searching. I haven't looked too closely at the source, but it looks like it's creating sets of file-backed hash-structures that is `mmap`ed when possible.

Comment: If you're after a document retrieval system (type some search terms and find the most relevant documents), google TF-IDF (term frequency-inverse document frequency). It's a metric designed to compensate for the differences in term frequency. (It doesn't normally work with ngrams, but it's not clear to me why you want them).